# Disable wheelEvent for QGraphicsView only, and not for the inside widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QGraphicsView` that have widgets as `QGraphicsProxyWidget` that are with `QScrollArea`. I am trying to disable the `wheelEvent` for the `QGraphicsView` without affecting the `wheelEvent` for the `ProxyWidget`:

```
class JobBuilderView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent) 
        .
        .
        .
        self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, qobject, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.Wheel and
            qobject is self.viewport()):
            modifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if modifiers == Qt.ControlModifier:
                zoomOutFactor = 1 / self.zoomInFactor
                if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                    zoomFactor = self.zoomInFactor
                    self.zoom += self.zoomStep
                else:
                    zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
                    self.zoom -= self.zoomStep

                clamped = False
                if self.zoom < self.zoomRange[0]: self.zoom, clamped = 
                self.zoomRange[0], True
                if self.zoom > self.zoomRange[1]: self.zoom, clamped = 
                self.zoomRange[1], True
                if not clamped or self.zoomClamp is False:
                    self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
                return True
            else:
                event.ignore()
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(qobject, event)
```

But, this approach disable the `wheelEvent` for all `ProxyWidgets`.

Is there any solution to this problem ?

I have changed the call as suggest by @musicamante, but the zooming functionality I am implementing is not working as it supposed to be using `event.type() == QEvent.Wheel` and `event.angleDelta().y() > 0`:

```
def eventFilter(self, qobject, event):
    zoomInFactor = 1.25
    zoomClamp    = True     
    zoom         = 10
    zoomStep     = 1
    zoomRange    = [0, 10]
    if event.type() == event.GraphicsSceneWheel:
        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() and Qt.ControlModifier:
            qobject.wheelEvent(event)
            zoomOutFactor = 1 / self.zoomInFactor
            if event.delta() == 120:
                zoomFactor = self.zoomInFactor
                self.zoom += self.zoomStep
            elif event.delta() == -120:
                zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
                self.zoom -= self.zoomStep

            clamped = False
            if self.zoom < self.zoomRange[0]: self.zoom, clamped = self.zoomRange[0], True
            if self.zoom > self.zoomRange[1]: self.zoom, clamped = self.zoomRange[1], True
            if not clamped or self.zoomClamp is False:
                self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
            
            return True
        else:
            qobject.wheelEvent(event)
            event.setAccepted(True)
        
            return True 
    return super().eventFilter(qobject, event)
```

Any suggestions, how can I fix this zooming functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the view receives an input event it creates a *graphics scene event*based on it, and sends it to the scene. For wheel events, it is a [QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenewheelevent.html).

If the scene *does* accept the event (which usually means that an item has handled it<sup>[1]</sup>), the event is *not* propagated to the parent, just like it happens for any other event for standard widgets.

For graphics views, if the scene does not accept the event, it then automatically sends the original wheel event to the scroll bars (the default implementation of QAbstractScrollArea).

If the event has to be ignored, the solution is to always set the event as accepted *after* calling the base implementation.

For subclasses:

```
class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        super().wheelEvent(event)
        event.setAccepted(True)
```

Alternatively, installing an event filter on the scene:

```
class JobBuilderView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent) 
        # ...
        self.scene().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.GraphicsSceneWheel:
            obj.wheelEvent(event)
            event.setAccepted(True)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

<sup>[1] handling an event and its accepted state do not always coincide: an event can be handled *and* ignored (which normally propagates it to the parent), or it can be *not* handled and still be accepted. The former is the case of mouse move events for widgets that could only change the appearance of the widget while the parent still needs to handle it for other reasons, while the latter happens when an event should not be propagated to the parent (a mouse press on a disabled widget).</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I have edit the zoom functionality based on your suggestions (above), but using `event.GraphicsSceneWheel` I changed the `event.angleDelta()` to `delta()` and this is not acting as what it should be !

Comment: @zezo please explain what you mean by "is not acting as what it should be".

Comment: The new zooming function using `event.GraphicsSceneWheel` is acting as the `QGraphicsScene` default zooming, no overridden is happening (very large zooming factor). But the old zooming function using `QEvent.Wheel`, I can see it is different from the default zooming functionality (small zooming factor).  If you have a better way to override the  default zooming, would be great (all I need is a small zooming factor when the wheel button is run) !

Comment: @zezo don't do the zoom from the event filter using the scene wheel event, just implement it from the [`viewportEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#viewportEvent).